# Opportunity cost of coins locked in HTLC

Tags: lightning-network, hash-time-locked-contract, micropaymentchannels, fee-estimation, micropayments

If a party agrees to lock coins in HTLC for payment (having hashlock for time T), and it receives a fee f if the HTLC succeeds, then does it mean that the opportunity cost of coins locked in HTLC is f? If so, I find a bit weird, because fee is function of the coins transferred for payment via a channel and not of the time T, so this makes the two situation invariant, party A willing to lock \alpha coins in HTLC having timelock T1 and another party B locking same \alpha coins in HTLC having timelock T2 where T1>T2. Assuming both of them use the same fee rate policy, then both receive the same fee say f_{\alpha}. If both the HTLCs are canceled just before the respective timeout, is the loss just the fee f_{\alpha}? Or shall the loss be the quantified as the the coins it would have gained had it utilized \alpha coins in the next T1 (or T2) units?